# Deep Linking when the app is not installed in the device

Tags: reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

I have this case where when clicked a `link` I redirect the user to the app using deep linking (made with RN) if the app is installed.

However, if the app is not installed instead of displaying error or a popup, I need to navigate to another route in the `web`, example: `/web-login`. I created the link for my app and it works, how do I test if the user has the app installed in the device, so then I can navigate to the other route if the user does't have it.

If the app is not installed I get something like: Browser cannot open the page because the address is invalid.